# Invoke / call Kindle Fire's native AwesomePlayer via Android intent - is it possible?

Tags: video, youtube, kindle-fire

I am trying to play a YouTube video on a Kindle Fire HD. On common Android devices is simple since Intent.ACTION_VIEW invokes the pre-installed YouTube app. Based on the logs, on the Kindle, which lacks the YouTube app, the Intent.ACTION_VIEW invokes the native Silk browser which loads the YouTube page and from there when clicking the Play button (overlapping the video thumb) the Kindle will invoke the native AwesomePlayer.

11-20 11:23:45.392: I/AwesomePlayer(107): Awsomeplayer is created

...

11-20 11:23:46.431: D/AwesomePlayer(107): Mime = video/avc

11-20 11:23:46.431: D/AwesomePlayer(107): Mime = audio/mp4a-latm

11-20 11:23:46.431: D/AwesomePlayer(107):  getTrackAudioVideoProfile audioOrVideo=2

11-20 11:23:46.431: D/AwesomePlayer(107): Play - AUDIO/VIDEO

...

I would like to bypass the Silk browser and launch directly Kindle's native "AwesomePlayer" from my android activity. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer from Amazon:

You cannot directly invoke the "Awesomeplayer" components to play Youtube videos on Kindle Fire HD, bypassing the Silk web browser.

The issue is that you do not have access to the actual Youtube video file - you have a link to the page where the video file is played. Without the path to the video file itself, you cannot call the player on the video file directly. Therefore, in the absence of a Youtube application, you need to invoke the Silk web browser.

Hope this information helps you.

See http://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=459